# Bootstrap column changes size inappropriately to text inside /text doesn't stay inside

Tags: html, css, text, position

I have 3 bootstrap columns and the problem is:
1. column: column do not 'grow' when the text inside is getting bigger, so the text doesn't stop where the column ends.
2. column: when the text is not just a single word, but for example 2 words (xxx xxx) the column doubles

How can I change that so the column which is a circle stays the same and the text stays INSIDE the column?
Thanks!

Html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="one" class="col-md-1">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
  <div id="two"class="col-md-1">xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</div>
  <div id="three"class="col-md-1">xxxx</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.row {
font-size:18px;
}
#one{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:#00b3b3;
border-radius:50%;
margin-left:150px;
width:240px;
hight:50px;
line-height:250px;
text-align:center;
}
 #two{
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#00b3b3;
 border-radius:50%;
 margin-left:100px;
 width:240px;
 hight:50px;
 line-height:250px;
 text-align:center;
}

#three{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:#00b3b3;
border-radius:50%;
margin-left:100px;
width:240px;
hight:50px;
line-height:250px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: height is spelled wrong on css

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a specific height on each of these circles?

Answer (score 0):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

This property will break the word and wrap it to the next line. I believe this is what you are asking.

As for why the columns do not 'grow' it's because you are setting the width and height -- remove that and it should grow as you progress.

```
.row {
 font-size:18px;
}
#one{
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#00b3b3;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-left:150px;
  text-align:center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
 #two{
     cursor:pointer;
     background-color:#00b3b3;
     border-radius:50%;
     margin-left:100px;
     text-align:center;
     word-wrap: break-word;
 }

 #three{
   cursor:pointer;
   background-color:#00b3b3;
   border-radius:50%;
   margin-left:100px;
   text-align:center;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

Note: It's super helpful if you can supply a JSFiddle or Bootply link in the future.

Comment: Thanks. word-wrap: break-word; helps so the text stays inside the column but there is now a huge gap between the text on the first line and text on the second line) and also when I remove width and height, the column won't be a circle anymore-I just want it to stay a circle (all 3 columns circles should have the same size).

Comment: @learningcoding That's because you have a line-height of 250px

Comment: I've updated your css above -- Again, your problem isn't super specific to what you are trying to accomplish. You can also share these class names(or IDs) to share properties. You are declaring the same exact values for different properties. Instead of ID 1,2,3 -- maybe try class ="column"

Comment: Thanks but when I remove width and height, the circle is just as small as the text and if I remove line-height, somehow all words after the first one are invisible..

Comment: @learningcoding - I think you need to be more specific in your explanation on what you are looking for. Add a height: 200px; to the css